# How to produce contour plot in R from matrix

Tags: r, matrix, contour

I have a file containing an nxn matrix of numeric values with a header row and column containing labels.

I want to produce a contour plot of the values with R (2.14.x) so I am loading in the matrix like so:

`mat <- as.matrix(read.table("myfile", row.names=1, sep=",", header=TRUE))`

and then attempting to produce a contour plot by:

`contour(rownames(mat), colnames(mat), mat)`

but I get the error:

```
Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

An example matrix that produces the problem contains:

```
,1,2,3
1,827786,672544,622597
2,674201,651413,533766
3,626531,533179,489844
```

What's going wrong and how do I fix it?
I'm very new to R so I might be doing something stupid here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

D'oh. Must've misread some documentation on the way - `contour(mat)` works fine.

I thought from docs like http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/index.php/R/Contour_Plots that I needed to split out the x,y,z.

Comment: if you've got the x,y vectors and z matrix then `contour(list(x=x,y=y,z=z))` should do it with the right axes. See also `image`. Defaults are 1:nrow or ncols so unless your x and y coords are meaningful (like geographic coordinates) you'll do fine with just `contour(z)`.