# R: how to plot contour lines to represent density distribution in a matrix?

Tags: r, plot, bioinformatics, contour, density-plot

I want to plot a contour plot from two matrices: mat1 and mat2. Here's the beginning of mat1:

```
[1] 0.031445000 0.031998580 0.037815850 0.050032810 0.066761480 0.074132810 0.075448150 0.079179210 0.085722410 0.103220600 0.131116300 0.177236000
[14] 0.194627400 0.236644700
```

and here's the beginning of mat2:

```
[1] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.184210e-05 2.968287e-05 3.843773e-05 6.345658e-05 9.110675e-05 9.749519e-05 1.064792e-04 1.849712e-04 2.306780e-04
[11] 2.638524e-04 2.700246e-04 4.042935e-04 4.639618e-04 5.564263e-04 6.211335e-04 6.377825e-04 6.447199e-04 6.522688e-04 6.623886e-04 6.754198e-04
```

My code is:

```
x2=seq(mat1)
y2=seq(mat2)
z = outer(mat1, mat2)
filled.contour(x2, y2, z)
```

But I get a plot that graphs values that are completely different from what I have in my matrices. It also uses colors to show density. But I want contour LINES to represent density. What function should I use?

I also tried to do:

```
filled.contour(mat1, mat2)
```

The error msg I'm getting is:

```
Error in contour.default(x1, y1) : increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected
```

which doesn't make sense because the values in the matrices are already increasing.

Comment: Oops sry, it was a careless mistake. i just fixed it so everythings consistent. still same problem though.

Comment: have you tried `contour`?

Comment: Yes, it gives me the same plot, which is wrong. If I just use: `contour(mat1, mat2)` the error msg is: `Error in contour.default(x1, y1) : increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected`, which is weird because my values are already increasing in the matrices.

Comment: Why aren't your mat1 and mat2 vectors the same length?

Comment: they are, i just select the start of the 2 matrices to show here. but yea, they are actually the same length.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to produce contour plot in R from matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218541/how-to-produce-contour-plot-in-r-from-matrix)

Comment: What do you want to represent? mat1 and mat2 as you showed are vectors not matrix, so that kind of representation doesn't make a lot of sense for vectors. Additionally z is the outer product of those two vectors (hence a matrix), so indeed it doesn't have the same values as mat1 and mat2 but each cell is a product of a value from mat1 and mat2. Finally if you want contour lines and not a heatmap you should indeed use function `contour` as @MatthewPlourde suggested.